# Hibernate criteria with dynamic OR restrictions

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, restriction, restrictions

I would like to add OR restricions dynamically to a Hibernate criteria based on the number of elements on an array.

In the example below, `Project` is an entity, and a `@OneToMany` property of the `User` entity. `Project` entity has a property called `name`. `db.getSes()` provides the current `Session`.

My current approach is

```
String[] project_name_filters = {"Project Name 1","Project Name 2"};

Criteria q = db.getSes().createCriteria(User.class);

if(project_name_filters.length > 0) {
    q.createAlias("project", "project");

    LogicalExpression or_exp = null;

    for(int ix_prj = 0 ; ix_prj < project_name_filters.length ; ix_prj++) {
            or_exp = Restrictions.or (or_exp,Restrictions.eq("project.name", project_name_filters[ix_prj]));
        }   

    q.add(or_exp);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<User> users = (List<User>) q.list();
```

but the initialization of `or_exp = null` is not appropriate.

I am not even sure if this is the way to implement a dynamic set of OR restrictions on a hibernate query.

How should I do it?

Comment: Start with a valid but impossible condition.

Comment: so the structure is ok, I just need to initialize or_exp as false. But how to do it correctly?. Can you give me an example of a valid but impossible condition?

Comment: That's why I commented instead of answering - I've only done this with raw SQL strings :)

In raw SQL, you'd start with something like `1 != 1` and add `OR` statements to that. I don't know Hibernate criteria well enough to give the equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with something that is certain to be false.

You can use [Restrictions.sqlRestriction](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction(java.lang.String)) to construct such a condition using raw SQL:

```
Criterion impossibleCriterion = Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(1=0)");
LogicalExpression or_exp = Restrictions.or(impossibleCriterion, impossibleCriterion);
```